# Download file not working with iframe

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe

I'm making an express application, and am having trouble exporting a file when the user clicks "download".

My approach as to make an ajax request to the server with the content, and then on the server, create the file and send back the file path. From there, I adjust the `src` attribute of an `iframe` element with the file path.

But, nothing is happening on Chrome (or any browser, actually). If I look at the *network* tab of the inspector, it shows that it received the file OK (with a 200 response code), and the content is there. Also, the `iframe` has the correct `src`. I'd like a download dialog to popup, but can't seem to get it.

Any ideas? Thank you!

---

**Example Code**:

*app.js* (server)

```
app.post('/create-html', function(req, res) {

    // explicitly set the headers on the server
    res.header('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
    res.header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="test.html"')

    var html      = req.body.content
       , name      = "test.html"
       , filepath  = (__dirname + "/public/files/" + name)
       , json_resp = {
            data: ''
          , err: false
         };

    fs.writeFile( filepath, html, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        // write the file and res.send the json_resp, so we can
        // access the filename on the client
    })
})
```

*script.js* (client)

```
$("#export-html").click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var html = $("#html-wrapper").html(); // the html of the file we want to make

    $.ajax({
          method: "POST"
        , url: "/create-html"
        , headers: {
            "Content-Disposition": 'attachment; filename="test.html"'
          }
        , type: "JSON"
        , success: function(resp) {
              var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe")
                , fp_prefix = "/files/"
                , fp = fp_prefix + resp.data; // ex: "/files/test.html" - the path where the file can be accessed

              iframe.src = fp
          }
    })

})
```

I'm getting `200`s when POSTing to the server (`/create-html`), and when the server is sending the data back (`test.html`). The content of the `test.html` file shows up in the web inspector, and going to `/files/test.html` shows the page. But, **I can't get it to download the HTML**.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any example or codes?

Comment: Take a look at the content coming back and make sure you have the correct HTTP Response Header: Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=<file name.ext>. Also you could trying a plugin I created to help with doing file downloads. It uses an iframe as well and is well tested: http://johnculviner.com/post/2012/03/22/Ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads-with-jQuery-File-Download.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the note, @JohnCulviner. I am using that header in the response object of Express before I'm sending it back. I can verify that in the Inspector, as well.

Any other ideas?

Comment: What's showing in the iframe?  If the browser isn't treating it as a possible download, it seem like it should be doing something else instead (such as displaying it).

Comment: Hey @Brilliand, I'm giving the iframe a class to hide it visually, but when I remove that class, it is shown within the iFrame. So, it's grabbing the data correctly - just not downloading it.

Comment: Try setting the content-type to `application/octet-stream` - not a very good solution, but it would be nice to know that that works at least.  Assuming that works, there might be something wrong with your `Content-Disposition` header - you might want to post the line of code that sets that header, and/or the raw headers as Chrome reports them (click "View Source" next to "Request Headers").

Comment: Whoops - you're setting the iframe's src to the direct path to the file?  Is the `Content-Disposition` header being sent in response to the actual request where the file is retrieved?  It has to be sent as part of the exact response that is supposed to be treated as a download.  (IIRC it's kinda hard to set specific headers on requests to a file that isn't processed server-side, which is why I ask.)

Comment: Hey all, thanks for your help thus far! @Derek and everyone else, I've added some sample code above. Hopefully it can help with solving this. Would appreciate any help if something looks fishy!

Answer (score 1):

with ExpressJS you use this:

```
apt.get('/create-html', function (req, res) {
  var name       = "test.html"
      , filepath = (__dirname + "/public/files/" + name);

  res.download(filepath, name);
});
```